# problems piping in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipe

We have the following example in node.js

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var proxy = http.createClient(8083, '127.0.0.1')
    var proxy_request = proxy.request(request.method, request.url, request.headers);
    proxy_request.on('response', function (proxy_response) {
        proxy_response.pipe(response);
        response.writeHead(proxy_response.statusCode, proxy_response.headers);
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        request.pipe(proxy_request);
    },3000);
}).listen(8081, '127.0.0.1');
```

The example listen to a request in 127.0.0.1:8081 and sends it to a dummy server (always return 200 OK status code) in 127.0.0.1:8083.

The problem is in the pipe among the input stream (readable) and output stream (writable) when we have a async module before (in this case the setTimeOut timing). The pipe doesn't work and nothing is sent to dummy server in 8083 port.

Maybe, when we have a async call (in this case the setTimeOut) before the pipe call, the inputstream change to a state "not readable", and after the async call the pipe doesn't send anything.

This is just an example...we test it with more async modules from node.js community with the same result (ldapjs, etc)...

We try to fix it with:
- request.readable =true; //before pipe call
- request.pipe(proxy_request, {end : false});
with the same result (the pipe doesn't work).

Can anybody help us?

Comment: pipes definitely work in node. I am using them in several places in my own project. There are good examples of how to use in the node docs on streams, and in the request module docs

Comment: You and I definitely seem to have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182725/http-request-stream-not-readable-outside-of-request-handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this works as of 0.8.0. I didn't try in 0.6.11+