# HTTP request stream not readable outside of request handler

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a fairly complicated multi-node proxy, and at one point I need to handle an HTTP request, but read from that request outside of the "http.Server" callback (I need to read from the request data and line it up with a different response at a different time). The problem is, the stream is no longer readable. Below is some simple code to reproduce the issue. Is this normal, or a bug?

```
function startServer() {
    http.Server(function (req, res) {
        req.pause();

        checkRequestReadable(req);

        setTimeout(function() {
        checkRequestReadable(req);
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout(function() {
        res.end();
        }, 1100);
    }).listen(1337);
    console.log('Server running on port 1337');
}

function checkRequestReadable(req) {
    //The request is not readable here!
    console.log('Request writable? ' + req.readable);
}

startServer();
```

Comment: I wanted to add that the req.on('data') does work, but ultimately, I want to get req.pipe(... working outside of the request handler.

Comment: If someone understands what's happening here, I'd love to understand better why this doesn't work.   I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as of 0.8.0. I didn't try in 0.6.11+

Comment: this doesn't work for me in 0.8.2. :(   Same issue - feel like I'm missing something architecturally in Node.js.   Then again, they changed all of this in 0.10, so perhaps not.

Answer (score 2):

It working in v0.8.22

```
server$ node http_test.js 
Server running on port 1337
Request writable? true
Request writable? true
Request writable? true
Request writable? true
^Cserver$ node -v
v0.8.22
server$
```